# Библиотека для работы с формами Python

Tags: python

подскажите пожалуйста библиотеки для создания и дальнейшей работы с формами отправки данных.

Хочу сделать программу, которая собой представляет страницу формы, куда подставляешь свои данные, после чего они вносятся в определённые места страницы.

Comment: С какими формами?..

Comment: Да всё понятно с какими формами! Я работаю с Flask. Вот Вам лайк за негатив!)

Comment: @VadimVoskresensky (и Вячеслав :), ознакомьтесь пожалуйста с данной статьей справки: [Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Для вас может быть очевидно о каких формах идет речь (причем вполне возможно что Вячеслав и Вадим думают о разных формах), но это не очевидно для других. Вопрос нужно исправить так, чтобы всем было понятно о чем идет речь.

Comment: WTForms см здесь: https://pythonru.com/uroki/11-rabota-s-formami-vo-flask

Comment: Да, можно и с изображениями женских форм поработать, но это уже нейронная сеть :) Так что хотелось бы уточнения, какие формы.

Comment: @nomnoms12 (Vadim Voskresensky, Assur и Alioshca Z), спасибо за ответы и советы. Свой вопрос поправил, извините за неудобство.